# Importance of the lifetime of the DbContext in database-first & code-first application development

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

I am learning ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework 6.1.

When I read about `DbContext` class, I found that it not only manages database connection but also keeps track of the changes in the data. I want to understand how I can manage the lifetime of `DbContext`. But the architect is saying that I need not bother about `DbContext` lifetime because our product is taking "database-first" (using EDMX file) approach and all logic will actually reside in stored procedures.

Can you throw some light on what `DbContext` (or `ObjectContext`) has to do with 
the design approach (code first vs database first) i follow?

Is it the case that we need not bother about lifetime of `DbContext` (e.g. keeping it live & common for entire business flow or creating new one for every step of the same business flow) when I am going "database first" approach?

Comment: It sounds to me like your architect person is telling your that you won't be using EF as most people do... I think he's telling that you will be using existing stored procedures for data manipulation instead of updating objects etc.  I personally prefer using EF as it was intended and only using stored procedures when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DbContext` is your line to the database, so if you're using EF as it "should" be used or not, you need to manage the life cycle of the `DbContext`. If you over use a `DbContext` the memory footprint can get unnecessarily large. Remember a `DbContext` doesn't equate exactly to a connection, so disposing of them doesn't have such a large cost.

If you're not using change tracking, consider using the method `AsNoTracking()` which will drastically increase performance of large queries.